# Create multiple buttons with sub windows in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have Accountid column in a Dataframe. Now I am using Tkinter to draw some gui. For each Accountid I want to create a separate button.My code is able to do that. But after this, for each button I want to create a subwindow, which would contain some columns for each Accountid. Now the problem is that my code creates sub-window for each button, but it fetches the columns for only the last Accountid.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        for id in df['AccountId']:##for each id create a button

            new_win_button = tk.Button(self, text=id, 
                                   command= self.new_window)
            new_win_button.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)


    def new_window(self):

        top = tk.Toplevel(self)# create sub window
        print (id)
        #print (id is 'id')
        label = tk.Label(top, text=s3.loc[s3.AccountId == id][['AccountId','confidence','lift']])

        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this loop :

```
for id in df['AccountId']:##for each id create a button

            new_win_button = tk.Button(self, text=id, 
                                   command= self.new_window)
            new_win_button.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)
```

`id` is a local variable to the class `Example`. And `id` is set to the last value of `df['AccountId']` at the end of the above for loop. for example:

```
for i in range(0,10):
  pass
print i
```

Result:

> 9

So in

```
label = tk.Label(top, text=s3.loc[s3.AccountId == id][['AccountId','confidence','lift']])
```

the comparison `s3.AccountId == id` will always comapare with the latest value of `id` that's why you are always getting the columns for only the last Accountid.

**workaround** :

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk() #declare root in global scope for simplicity


class new_button:

    def __init__(self,A_id):

        self.id=A_id
        but = tk.Button(root,text=self.id,command=self.new_window)
        but.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)



    def new_window(self):

        top = tk.Toplevel(root)# create sub window

        label = tk.Label(top, text=s3.loc[s3.AccountId == self.id][['AccountId','confidence','lift']])

        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in df['AccountId']:##for each id create a button

            butt=new_button(A_id=i)

    root.mainloop()
```

created a `new_button` class which creates a unique button for each `AccountId` in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. But how to resolve this? Any suggestions.

Comment: @user2906657, provide a sample for `df` and `s3`